# How to design set & get method in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to design set & get method in React.js class component?

```
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';
export default class EditPopup extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
       super(props);
      

    this.state = {
        userInfoList: []
      };
    }

    setUsers(userArray)
    {
       setState({userInfoList: userArray});
    }
    getUsers()
    {
       return this.state.userInfoList;
    }

    ...

    render() { return(<div></div>); }
}
```

Above code have set&get method. I can set user list to call setUsers method. But setState() which in setUsers() method does not warrant set the user list immediately. So if i call getUsers() method after i set, i can't trust the array had applied by new data.

Many people said just use 'promise' but, it seems to make delay to wait. So the only solution that i thought was to make a new clone member array in class. And if i want to set a new user list then, i'll set the data to both. (state and new member array). Then if i want just a recent user list then i'll refer member array instead state.

But if i have many state then this will makes code messy. (Because i must make all the same members as state)

Is there have another best solution to design set&get method in React.js?

Comment: You shouldn't need a "get" function, when you update state the component will rerender and the updated state will simply be available right off `this.state`, which you can access within any lifecycle function and OFC `render`. What are you trying to do? Duplicating state is a react anti-pattern and violates the single source of truth principle.

Comment: If you'll add more details on your use case, maybe we can help you find a better solution

Comment: i want to make parent component to access the EditPopup(child) component's state.

Comment: Components reaching *into* other components to do *anything* is also an anti-pattern. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Data flows down the react tree, including callbacks, in the form of props. Loft state & behavior to a common ancestor.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if there are over 2 level deep of lifting, then is it much better solution to use redux or mobx?

Comment: Those are capable of much heavier lifting, much more than *just* a few levels of prop drilling, which is a design problem both solve for. For something a little lighter you may find the react [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) a little more wieldy (Redux is built on it but much more bolierplatey and can be confusing if you're unfamiliar).